# Field 'team' doesn't have a default value / Unhandled MySQL errno 1364. Unexpected behaviour possible

Tags: sql, lua, azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

I found this script online and i'm new to lua but i want to learn lua.
I have coding knowledge but not in lua.
I have tried to contact to owner of the script but i think he's busy in real to make it work for my latest trinitycore.

I will link the sql imported for commands aswell.

this is the lua error & sql:

> lua_scripts/Grumbo'z Guild Warz.lua:2083: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)
>   [1364] Field 'team' doesn't have a default value
>   Unhandled MySQL errno 1364. Unexpected behaviour possible.
>   commands for: RA : created.
>   lua_scripts/Grumbo'z Guild Warz.lua:508: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

Another error :

> [Eluna]: Error loading `lua_scripts/Grumbo'z Guild Warz.lua`
>   lua_scripts/Grumbo'z Guild Warz.lua:732:  expected near '=='

I've trying fixing it myself but none of my ideas were working.
Couldn't find anyone with the same kinda problems as mine.

Lua script is to long to post here so i'm trying to link it via pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/viVcmbz6

Sql command script is to long to post here so i'm trying to link it via pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/uA5SNFxp

Expected result :
This script should enable war between guilds & building guild buildings.

Comment: and would you mind to share your ideas? what have you tried? if there are nil values you have to find out why and fix the cause. that's pretty straight forward so why does that not work for you?

Comment: I've tried to locate the nil values and alter them but it seems I'm failing to locate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> lua_scripts/Grumbo'z Guild Warz.lua:508: attempt to index field '?' (a
>   nil value)

got to line 508:

```
GWCOMM[PLAYER_GUILD_ID].commands
```

`GWOCOMM[PLAYER_GUILD_ID]` is `nil`. Find out why.

> lua_scripts/Grumbo'z Guild Warz.lua:732: expected near '=='

go to line 732

```
if(GWARZ[LocId].  ==0)
```

There is nothing behind the index operator! This error can only be fixed if you understand what the program is supposed to do here.